# re findall function

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the [json](/questions/tagged/json) string:

```
s = '''
{"messages":[],

"fileToTestMapForAllFiles":{"/pfe/usp/include/nat_util.h":[{"profile":"Component_toxicity_L2VPN_L2CKT_L3VPN_VPLS_VMX","occam":0,"releases":"15.1 and after","image":"junos-x86-64-*.vmdk","feature":"-","platform":"-","testSystem":"inception.juniper.net","enhancedIp":0,"id":0,"testId":"2","gating":"GATING","mandatory":""},
{"profile":"Component_toxicity_ipv46_bfd_ae_ifstate_VMX","occam":0,"releases":"15.1 and after","image":"junos-x86-64-*.vmdk","feature":"-","platform":"-","testSystem":"inception.juniper.net","enhancedIp":0,"id":0,"testId":"8","gating":"NON_GATING","mandatory":""},
{"profile":"Component_toxicity_GRES_NSR_VMX","occam":0,"releases":"15.1 and after","image":"junos-x86-64-*.vmdk","feature":"-","platform":"-","testSystem":"inception.juniper.net","enhancedIp":0,"id":0,"testId":"9","gating":"GATING","mandatory":""},
{"profile":"Component_toxicity_mcast_VMX","occam":0,"releases":"15.1 and after","image":"junos-x86-64-*.vmdk","feature":"-","platform":"","testSystem":"inception.juniper.net","enhancedIp":0,"id":0,"testId":"10","gating":"GATING","mandatory":""},
{"profile":"RPD_PC_Basic_Sanity_ST","occam":1,"releases":"15.1 and after","image":"junos-x86-64-*.vmdk,junos-x86-32-*.vmdk","feature":"rpd","platform":"vmx","testSystem":"inception.juniper.net","enhancedIp":0,"id":0,"testId":"129","gating":"GATING","mandatory":""},
{"profile":"RPD_PC_MISC","occam":1,"releases":"15.1 and after","image":"-","feature":"BBE-SANITY","platform":"mx-neo","testSystem":"inception.juniper.net","enhancedIp":1,"id":0,"testId":"387","gating":"GATING","mandatory":"18.2DCB,15.1F6-S10,17.2X75-D90,15.1R7,16.1R7,17.3R3,17.4R2,18.1R1,"}]},
"fileToTestMappingNotExist":[],"filesNotAdded":[],"validationFailedForTheseFiles":[],"filesToAdd":[],"invalidPathNames":[]}
'''
```

I need to find pattern: `RPD_PC_<[anyword]>`, when I call:

```
print re.findall(r"RPD_PC_", s)
['RPD_PC_', 'RPD_PC_']
```

Because the string contains the string:

```
['RPD_PC_Basic_Sanity_ST'] ['RPD_PC_MISC']
```

What's the pattern which will only look for `RPD_PC_MISC`, not for `RPD_PC_Basic_Sanity_ST`?

Comment: can you give some more examples please

Comment: How are you supposed to tell them apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take whatever is there upto next `"`:

```
RPD_PC_[^"]+
```

`[^"]+` matches one or more characters upto next `"`.

A more robust approach would be to make sure the match is preceded by a `"`:

```
"(RPD_PC_[^"]+)
```

`re.findall` would print the captured group matches only.

A (zero-width) positive lookbehind would work too:

```
(?<=")RPD_PC_[^"]+
```

If you want to explicitly match a following `"`, use a lookahead:

```
(?<=")RPD_PC_[^"]+(?=")
```

**Example:**

```
In [124]: re.findall(r'RPD_PC_[^"]+', s)
Out[124]: ['RPD_PC_Basic_Sanity_ST', 'RPD_PC_MISC']

In [125]: re.findall(r'"(RPD_PC_[^"]+)', s)
Out[125]: ['RPD_PC_Basic_Sanity_ST', 'RPD_PC_MISC']

In [126]: re.findall(r'(?<=")RPD_PC_[^"]+', s)
Out[126]: ['RPD_PC_Basic_Sanity_ST', 'RPD_PC_MISC']
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to match `RPD_PC_MISC` only, match one or more characters that are not `_`/`"`, followed by a `"`:

```
(?<=")RPD_PC_[^_"]+(?=")
```

So:

```
In [127]: re.findall(r'(?<=")RPD_PC_[^_"]+(?=")', s)
Out[127]: ['RPD_PC_MISC']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but still i am looking for only ['RPD_PC_MISC']